# Remove Dojo from XPages globally

Tags: xpages

At http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/11182010085538.html and http://dpastov.blogspot.dk/2011/01/trying-to-get-full-control-over-xpage.html it's explained to set

`xsp.client.script.libraries=none`

in the xsp.properties file.

I did so but got the following error then

http://pastebin.com/9qiUVPri

It's running on Domino 8.5.3FP2

Any ideas for what reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable the resource aggregation too:

```
xsp.resources.aggregate=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.
First thing is this setting in the xsp.properties

```
xsp.resources.aggregate=true
```

If it is set to false, then one can use also

```
xsp.client.script.libraries=none
```

No Errors any more on the page.
The html now looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="view:label1">Test</span></body>
</html>
```