# Disable Extensions Library

Tags: xpages

My newly set up database generates the following lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.registerModulePath('extlib', '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib');</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.de-de/@Eya.js"></script>
```

As far as I found out, it comes from the extensions library.
But I had not activated it at the xsp.properties file / Page Generation > XPages Libraries

How can I get rid of it.
I think it has something to do with my previous question [Remove Dojo from XPages globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939408/remove-dojo-from-xpages-globally)

Comment: The OneUI2.1 Theme set this values

Comment: It's always a good idea to write an answer when you figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OneUI2.1 Theme set this values.
I removed it and everything is under my control :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Application Properties/Advanced of your domino database and deselect the extlib libraries.

[Disable extlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kdDG.png)

Comment: As I wrote there is nothing selected. It was set up by the theme OneUI2.1. I removed it.

Comment: Just so this all goes to the same place, I *DID* have it selected in the properties/advanced. I unchecked it and still had problems. Once you uncheck it, you have to restart the whole notes client. Some caching going on here.....